# Is it okay to say "Let me start from question No.5 in this quiz"?

Tags: word-usage

I want to tell my teacher that I have done 4 questions in the quiz and would like to start from the fifth question.

Is it okay to say "Let me start from question No.5 in this quiz"?

Is `question No.x` an acceptable usage in formal English? What if it's not the fifth question but the first one or some other numbers, will it still work?

Comment: The grammar is fine, it's also acceptable in formal English, and all the numbers work. My issue is with the writing "No.5". This feels like an old fashioned style, but I'm in Canada, and it may still be common in the UK. In the Americas, we would use "#5" or "number 5" when writing.

Comment: Your context is a bit weird. If you have already done four questions of the quiz, in what sense are you starting?  Do you mean "I now start question number 5"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds fine, although it's also acceptable, and perhaps a bit more idiomatic, to say:

> Let me start from question five in this quiz.

Given the context (speaking to an authority figure), you may say something like:

> I've done the first four questions, so can I start from question five?

It would be more correct to say "may" instead of "can", but this is not particularly idiomatic/common.

Also, depending on the precise context, you may actually just tell the teacher:

> I'm up to question five.

Comment: **Let me start.....** might not be the best way to address your teacher. Better to say: ** (As I have already answered the first four questions) may I start from question (number) five in the quiz?**

Comment: Or just lead in with “Please let me...”

Comment: Is it okay that I say `Let me start from question one in this quiz.`?

Comment: Oops, I missed the context here, please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you have completed questions 1 to 4 then a request like

> Can I start from question five, because {reason}.

"Let me" could be used but it sounds rather like pleading or demanding.

If you've done five questions, but not the first five

> Can I skip the questions that I've already done?

Your context is rather odd, in a quiz the answer would normally be "no" because the teacher wants to assess if you really can do those questions.  But on a worksheet for practice, it might be okay.